# Overriding `inherited` on STI class raises NoMethodError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, inheritance, rails-activerecord, single-table-inheritance

I have the following classes in my rails 4 app:

```
class ReceiptDocument < ActiveRecord::Base
  @foo

  self.inheritance_column = :document_type
  has_and_belongs_to_many :donations

  protected

    def self.inherited(subklass)
      subklass.inherit_attributes(@foo)
    end

    def self.inherit_attributes(foo)
      @foo = foo
    end
end

class ReceiptRequest < ReceiptDocument; end
class ReceiptResult < ReceiptDocument; end
```

The class instance variable `@foo` is set once at class definition, and should have the same value in all subclasses. I added the `inherited` override so that value would be accessible from both `ReceiptRequest` and `ReceiptResult`.

However, now when I call `ReceiptRequest.new`, I get:

```
pry(main)> DonationReceiptRequest.new
NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
from /gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:9:in `relation_delegate_class'
```

If I comment out that override, things return to normal. However, I can no longer share that value across all subclasses of `ReceiptDocument`.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Finally got this sorted.

The error seemed to be pointing me at some behind the scenes work that ActiveRecord was doing, so I dug in a bit further.

It seems that setting `self.inheritance_column` most likely overrides the `inherited` method. Honestly, I'm not sure what work is being done that my override was stomping on. But redefining that method as below fixed the issue:

```
def self.inherited(subklass)
  super # <--
  subklass.inherit_attributes(@foo)
end
```